# Can I combine two FoldList into one?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I want get something like this:

```
{{x, x}, {g[x, 1], f[x, 1]}, {g[g[x, 1], 2], 
  f[f[x, 1], 2]}, {g[g[g[x, 1], 2], 3], f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 3]}}
```

one way is `Transpose@{FoldList[f, x, {1, 2, 3}], FoldList[g, x, {1, 2, 3}]}`

Is it posibble only use  `FoldList` once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to argue for the superiority of the method you are already using, and suggest using an auxiliary function to simplify its application.

[`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html) and [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html) auto-compile, where possible, when the length of the third argument is greater than the value defined in `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "FoldCompileLength"]`.  Since it will be less likely for the combined form to compile (generally), for best performance I think you should not try to combine both functions into one.

I propose:

```
multiFoldList[fns_, start_, list_] := Transpose[FoldList[#, start, list] & /@ fns]
```

Usage and performance:

```
SeedRandom[1]
args = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3500000];

multiFoldList[{Plus, Times, #/2 + #2 &}, 0`, args] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.53
> ```

Compared to a combined form of the same operation:

```
FoldList[{#[[1]] + #2, #[[2]] #2, #[[3]]/2 + #2} &, {0`, 0`, 0`}, args] // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.702
> ```

If you wish to provide for the possibility of different starting ("x") values for each function you can use this form:

```
multiFoldList[fns_List, start_, list_] := 
  FoldList[##, list] & @@@ Thread[{fns, start}] // Transpose
```

Allowing:

```
multiFoldList[{Plus, Times, #/2 + #2 &}, {1`, 2`, 3`}, {10`, 11`, 12`, 13`, 14`}]
```

> ```
> {{1., 2., 3.}, {11., 20., 11.5}, {22., 220., 16.75}, {34., 2640., 20.375},
>  {47., 34320., 23.1875}, {61., 480480., 25.5938}}
> ```

Or a shared starting value as before:

```
multiFoldList[{Plus, Times, #/2 + #2 &}, 2.5, Range[2, 7]]
```

> ```
> {{2.5, 2.5, 2.5}, {4.5, 5., 3.25}, {7.5, 15., 4.625}, {11.5, 60., 6.3125},
>  {16.5, 300., 8.15625}, {22.5, 1800., 10.0781}, {29.5, 12600., 12.0391}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using `Rules` and `Pure` `Functions`:

```
{#, # /. f -> g} & /@ FoldList[f, x, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Gives:

```
{{x, x}, {f[x,1], g[x,1]}, {f[f[x,1], 2], g[g[x,1], 2]}, {f[f[f[x,1], 2], 3], g[g[g[x, 1], 2], 3]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread[FoldList[#, x, {1, 2, 3}] & /@ {f, g}]
```

> {{x, x}, {f[x,1], g[x,1]}, {f[f[x,1], 2], g[g[x,1], 2]}, {f[f[f[x,1], 2], 3], g[g[g[x, 1], 2], 3]}}

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to write it with just a single `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[{f[#[[1]], #2], g[#[[2]], #2]} &, {x, x}, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {{x, x}, {f[x, 1], g[x, 1]}, {f[f[x, 1], 2], 
    g[g[x, 1], 2]}, {f[f[f[x, 1], 2], 3], g[g[g[x, 1], 2], 3]}} *)
```

Comment: @expression what do you expect if you multiply `True` by an integer! Additionally you are introducing a function that returns one part but using it in a way that requires the output to have two parts. ...And so on. Some effort is needed on your part to understand answers provided.